# help figuring out why this output is "01"

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
vector<int> v(5);
v[0]=0; v[1]=1; v[2]=2; v[3]=3; v[4]=4;

for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    v.pop_back();
for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    cout<<v[i];
cout<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

i am confused as to why the output is "01". i would think the output is "0"

Comment: ouch ouch ..... please let it not be production code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trace each iteration of the first for-loop through:

```
i   v.size()    v (before pop_back)
0   5           0,1,2,3,4
1   4           0,1,2,3
2   3           0,1,2
3   2           0, 1
```

And the loop stops there (not popping when i == 3) since `3 < 2` is false. So the final contents of `v` after the loop is [ 0, 1 ].

Answer (score 3):

If v.size() is evaluated each loop, then the loop limit is coming down as you pop items off your vector. It must pop the last 3 off before bailing out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned, second loop meets stopping condition at 3rd iteration, since i val is 3 and vector size is 2.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Geez u mentioning me this after 1 year and 5 months. Ridiculos

Comment: Seems to be a re-occurring issue that you have.

Comment: so as your comment reoccured :)

Comment: The comment is generated by the new review system, your answers were picked up by that so there must be some form of consistency.

Comment: should i delete my comment to avoid that
??